# Apache 2.2.12 JkMount not recognized

Tags: apache, tomcat7

I am using Apache 2.2.12 and Tomcat 7.0.61.

I have omitted several config files from this post because all but one context root is working.

I have several jkmounts in a vhost.conf file in the vhost directory of apache2. All of them work except one. I have the same config file in a test environment that works with no problem. Same syntax and everything. The files have been diff checked and checked for line ending errors. We are running a sles 11 box packaged by Novell. The service context returns a Forbidden.

error log:

```
 - [Wed Mar 22 06:09:54 2017] [error] [client requestingip] client denied by server configuration: /srv/www/htdocs/services
 - [Wed Mar 22 06:09:54 2017] [error] [client requestingip] client denied by server configuration: /srv/www/htdocs/favicon.ico, referer: https://sub.domain.com/services/request-path/
```

I am at complete loss why this context `/srv/ww/htdocs/` is taking precedence when none of the other services on the same worker in the same file hosted in the same webapps folder do this.

Important to note that if I call the service like this directly at Tomcat:
`sub.domain.com:8080/services/path-to-function/##`.

It works, but we should not have to hit Tomcat directly. Below is the mount etc - some details spoofed for obvious reasons. Other things to note:

1. I ran rcapache2 configtest "Syntax OK"
2. I ran dos2unix file-name (just in case) the file was created and modified on a Linux box via PuTTY.
3. Multiple other rest and soap services are running on this box. All wars in the same webapp folder and contexts declared in the same vhost.conf file.
4. in mod_jk.log file Loglevel "trace" I do not see where it even attempts to map the context URI

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
ServerName sub.domain.com:80
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
TransferLog /var/log/apache2/access_log

SSLEngine off

Alias /services "/opt/apache-tomcat-<version-num>/webapps/services"
<Directory "/opt/apache-tomcat-<version-num>/webapps/services">
</Directory>

JkMount /services/* worker1
<Location "/services">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI Multiviews
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Services"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL ldaps://directory.domain.com/o=organization-tree?uid
Require ldap-group cn=service-users,o=oragnization-tree
AuthLDAPBindDN cn=user,o=organization-tree
AuthLDAPBindPassword p@ssWord
</Location>

<Location "/services/WEB-INF/">
Deny from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have reviewed multiple threads, documentation and sites on this issue.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the clean up and assistance. I was able to resolve this issue. I will post the fix momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

While testing through multiple config options I realized that each vHost config should have either a ip address or a domain proceeded by a port. The warning that lead me to this realization was the warning by apache that there was overlap on the use of port 80 and the first will take precedence. By adding a unique name to each VirtualHost,assigning each domain to a separate IP and restarting apache I was able to eliminate the issue.

example:

```
<VirtualHost hostname-service.domain-1.com:80>
ServerName sub.domain-1.com:80
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
TransferLog /var/log/apache2/access_log

SSLEngine off

Alias /services "/opt/apache-tomcat-<version-num>/webapps/services"
<Directory "/opt/apache-tomcat-<version-num>/webapps/services">
</Directory>

JkMount /services/* worker1
<Location "/services">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI Multiviews
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Services"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL ldaps://directory.domain.com/o=organization-tree?uid
Require ldap-group cn=service-users,o=oragnization-tree
AuthLDAPBindDN cn=user,o=organization-tree
AuthLDAPBindPassword p@ssWord
</Location>

<Location "/services/WEB-INF/">
Deny from all
</Location></VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost hostname-service.domain-2.com:80>
ServerName sub.domain-2.com:80
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
TransferLog /var/log/apache2/access_log

SSLEngine off

Alias /services "/opt/apache-tomcat-<version-num>/webapps/services"
<Directory "/opt/apache-tomcat-<version-num>/webapps/services">
</Directory>

JkMount /services/* worker1
<Location "/services">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI Multiviews
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Services"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL ldaps://directory.domain.com/o=organization-tree?uid
Require ldap-group cn=service-users,o=oragnization-tree
AuthLDAPBindDN cn=user,o=organization-tree
AuthLDAPBindPassword p@ssWord
</Location>

<Location "/services/WEB-INF/">
Deny from all
</Location></VirtualHost>
```